# Dynamic Javascript when changing screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div class where I want change the css class name when resolution of the user's screen changes. The following script works:

```
if ( $(window).width() < 739) {     
  $("#default").toggleClass('classold classnew');
}
else {
  $("#default").toggleClass('classold classold');
}
```

But it has a problem. When I open a browser with a width of 600px and change it to full screen, the mobile class version is not updated. It only works when I reload the page.

How can I make this work without reloading the page?

Comment: Instead of this way why don't you use `media query`

Comment: Try `$(window).resize( function(){...`

Answer (score 3):

Move this code into a resize handler:

```
function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() < 739) {     
    $("#default").toggleClass('classold classnew');
    }
    else {
    $("#default").toggleClass('classold classold');
    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize(); // call once initially
```

---

You can also consider using CSS3 media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 739px) {
    /* rules for small screens */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 740px) {
    /* rules for large screens */
}
```

Comment: for css not understand how use, i want import javascript, read my answer to user "Hosch Nok". for "function resize()" i have copy and paste the code with my class name ,right ?, can you show me a example of complete code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve it using CSS as

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    /* your code */
}
@media (min-width: 740px) {
    /* your code */
}
</style>
```

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

**Why your script does't work**

Your if-else statement will be called on site load and then will never be touched again. For it to work properly you would have to trigger it on a resize event.

**Why you should not use this solution**

Whenever you can solve something with CSS only you should avoid using Javascript. One reason is performance, but there are also edge cases where using Javascript instead of CSS can result in strange behaviour. For example when you use the maximize function of the browser and get the new window size right after this can result in wrong results.

**How you should solve the problem**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 739px) {
    #default{
        //css rules for smaller screens
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 740px) {
    #default{
        //css rules for larger screens
    }
}
```

Comment: but i don't think i can insert javascript on css media querie ,right ??, this class depend by javascript i want call script1 for desktop version and script2 on mobile on same <div>, so this require change the class,What do you recommended?

Comment: as i said everything solvable with css only should be solved like that.

Comment: can you show me a example how import javascript with CSS media queries, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this, but as well as attaching to resize event, attach to load?

Also guys who are saying about media queries are right, but for JS it should be something like:

```
   $(window).on('resize load', function () {
      if ($(window).width() < 739) {
          $("#default").addClass('classnew').removeClass('classold')
      } else {
          $("#default").addClass('classold').removeClass('classnew')
      }
   });
```

Hope this works for you =)